# spring cloud contract POC

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to create an example POC for my team to use Spring cloud contract.

I was able to receive Green-Pass for Producer side but on Consumer side, I keep getting 
`No stubs or contracts were found for [com.datson:cloudcontract-producer:+:stubs] and the switch to fail on no stubs was set.`  The contracts are present.

I tried several user-case as described in the offical spring cloud document.

`@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.datson:cloudcontract-producer:+:8080", stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)`

`@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.datson:cloudcontract-producer:+:stubs"`

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-cdc-consumer-run

here is the consumer code sample: https://github.com/Yayan89/springboot-config-server/tree/master/cloudcontract-consumer

here is the producer code sample: https://github.com/Yayan89/springboot-config-server/tree/master/cloudcontract-producer

Might be something silly that I missed out.

Comment: Please check out the samples https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presented samples you need to install a jar in your local m2 to fetch it from the consumer side (please read the documentation on how to fetch the contracts directly from the drive). If you check this sample and the gradle build https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/scripts/runGradleBuilds.sh#L37 you will see that you should run sth like this

```
./gradlew build publishToMavenLocal
```

assuming that you have `maven-publish` plugin or

```
./gradlew build install
```

assuming that you have a `maven` plugin

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reply @MarcinGrejszzak, just one thing I want to make sure if I understand correctly.  Producer needs to publish mavenlocal (.m2) for consumer to be able to build it.  Is my statement correct?

`id 'maven-publish'`
and we need to add our producer in gradle/mvn build

```
implementation("com.datson:cloudcontract-producer:+:stubs") {
        transitive = false
    }
```

my code works now with

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL,
    ids = "com.datson:cloudcontract-producer:+:stubs:0.0.1:8090"
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LoanApplicationServiceTest {

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void given_WhenPassEvenNumberInQueryParam_ThenReturnEven() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/fraudcheck")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Even"));
}}
```

Comment: You don't need to add it to the classpath. If you do you can set the mode to CLASSPATH

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak 
Just a quick related question
In our architecture, our backend will take the jar-stubs file (it contains the json if I am correct) from our Artifactory. And in our frontend, they are using Angular, how will they communicate with our contract?  

I read the doc from https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/using.html#flows-provider-non-jvm but it is using producer as node.js.

Comment: It doesn't matter who the producer is. If the jar is in artifactory they can use the docker image to fetch the stubs and run them at given, predefined ports